# Background blinks on hover when adding new item to menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Working on simple menu where user can add new items. The problem is that when clicking on last div("new item"), new item created and moves last item to the right, triggering hover(last item blinks)

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")
var container = $('.container');
var newBtn = $('.new');

newBtn.on('click', function() {
 $('<div class="row">blinking new</div>').insertBefore(newBtn)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  height: 30px;
}
.row {
  background: green;;
  width: 100px;
}
.row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">firstg </div>
  <div class="row">second </div>
  <div class="new row">new item</div>
</div>
```

**Chrome**: latest item's background blinks when hover target changes.
**IE11**: when the new item added, IE not repaint menu and the latest item hover state will be preserved, even the cursor stay on newly added item.
[image]
If any workarounds exists to fix this behavior?

Comment: When you say "blink", do you really mean that the new item is initially yellow?

Comment: It blinks on Chrome(yellow to green), but on IE11  behavior is even worse, it remains yellow after adding item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a new element and inserting it before the button, you could change the button into the new element, and then create a new button.  That way, the hover state stays on the current element and doesn't have to switch:

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")
var container = $('.container');
var newBtn = $('.new');
function handleClick() {
    var newDiv = newBtn.clone();
    newDiv.insertAfter(newBtn);
    newBtn.html('blinking new');
    newBtn.off('click')
    newBtn = newDiv;
    newBtn.on('click', handleClick);
}
newBtn.on('click', handleClick)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  height: 30px;
}
.row {
  background: green;;
  width: 100px;
}
.row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">firstg </div>
  <div class="row">second </div>
  <div class="new row">new item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of the way you are inserting the new button. It inserts the new button and moves "new item" to the end. Because "new item" was in the hover state, when it gets moved over it is still in that state, but because your mouse is now positioned on the new button, that button gets the focus and turns yellow.

Instead, insert the new button with `.append()` to the end of the menu (therefore, your mouse stays positioned over the same button it has been the whole time and no new focusing happens at all) and then move the "new item" to the end of the menu with another `.append()`.

In other words, it's the combination of your `:focus` CSS selector and your `.insertBefore` way of adding the new content that is causing the issue. Using `.append()` instead of `.insertBefore` solves this.

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")
var container = $('.container');
var newBtn = $('.new');

newBtn.on('click', function() {
  // Append the new button to the end of the menu
  $(".container").append('<div class="row">blinking new</div>');
  
  // Move the "new item" button to the end of the menu
  $(".container").append(this);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  height: 30px;
}
.row {
  background: green;;
  width: 100px;
}
.row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">firstg </div>
  <div class="row">second </div>
  <div class="new row">new item</div>
</div>
```